# Is there any way to add overlays to bokeh plot highlighting certain areas based on x-axis datapoints. See picture below

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, bokeh

I am plotting some data on x-axis and y-axis which gives peaks. I want to highlight certain areas of the peaks in multiple colors.

I was able to get the plot but have no clue on how to add overlays to the plot

https://jascoinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/UV-fraction-collection.png

Answer (score 2):

You could use `BoxAnnotation` for this. One advantage is that it always span entire height of the plot.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [1, 3, 2, 8, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 9, 1, 2], line_width=2)
b1 = BoxAnnotation(left=3, right = 5, fill_color = 'red', fill_alpha = 0.5)
b2 = BoxAnnotation(left=9, right = 11, fill_color = 'green', fill_alpha = 0.5)
p.add_layout(b1)
p.add_layout(b2)
p.text([4, 10], [0, 0], ['area1', 'area2'], y_offset = -10, x_offset = -20)
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I like this option too.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Do you happen to know if there is a way to add text to these boxes? I went through the BoxAnnotation class and couldn't find anything that gives that option. I just want to add index numbers to these boxes.

Comment: You could use [text](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.text) or [Lebel](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html) for this. See updated code

Comment: How can we apply something like this repetitively over an extended datetime x-axis?  Like, highlight working hours in a day in a time series that, implied here, spans over multiple days?

Comment: I've answered my qestion by creating as many datetime ranges as needed, then looping over to add as many BoxAnnotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight an area by plotting another glyph over the line such as a vbar, but other glyphs like rectangles also work.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [1, 3, 2, 8, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 9, 1, 2], line_width=2)
p.vbar(x=[4, 10], width=2, bottom=0, top=10, color=['red', 'green'], alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: That's really cool. Thanks!

Can you use tuples to assign starting and end point of a vbar instead of a fixed width?

Comment: You can use a different width for every vbar by replacing `width=2` by `width=[2, 4]`. You have to use rectangles if you want to use fixed locations. https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#rectangles

Comment: Ok. BoxAnnotation solved this issue for me as of now. I will keep this option in mind too for future use. Thanks!!